# sum in existing rows according to years and regions in R

Tags: r

I have included  a 
[sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i0sE.png)
In my R code I have a loop that goes trough the regions (ES00, ES11, ES12, so on) and for the years (2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010).
What I would like to do is to sum in ES00 (it is empty now)the addition of the others regions (ES00=ES11+ES12+ES13) per each year.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: try to make it at least [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). A picture of your data is of no use.

Comment: Also include expected outcome.

Comment: Ok, sorry....I will do it next time. I am quite new on this issues.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy dataset based on your's

```
data = data.frame(c("ES00","ES00","ES11","ES11","ES12","ES12"),c(2006,2007,2006,2007,2006,2007),c(0,0,12,13,14,15))
names(data) = c("Region","Year","amount")
```

so this looks like following:

```
data
  Region Year amount
1   ES00 2006      0
2   ES00 2007      0
3   ES11 2006     12
4   ES11 2007     13
5   ES12 2006     14
6   ES12 2007     15
```

You can use a loop for every year in your data base and do the following:

```
data$amount[(data$Year==2006) & data$Region=="ES00"] = sum(data$amount[(data$Year==2006)&(data$Region!="ES00")])
```

If you want to get a little bit more fancy you can use `plyr` library
and since your metrics for region ES00 are 0 do the following:

```
ddply(data,.(Year),summarize, new_amount =sum(amount))
```

which will look something like this:

```
  Year new_amount
1 2006         26
2 2007         28
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (considering your dataframe name is 'data')

```
for (yr in 2006:2010){
for (i in 3:7){
data[data$Region=='ES00'& data$Year ==yr,i] = 
                sum(data[data$Region=='ES00' & data$Year==yr,i]
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  The issue is that I have  select a sample  from a big data. The common thing is that all the regions have the same pattern XX00, then, could it be possible to write Region == to a certain pattern?

Comment: Yes using grepl #regular expressions matching in R

Comment: for (yr in 2006:2010){
     for (i in 3:16){
       data[grepl("$00",data$Region),] & data$Year ==yr,i] = 
         sum(data[data$Region==nuts & data$Year==yr,i])
     }
   }

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to put the code in a proper way to be read. What I try to tell with the code above is that I got an error in the grepl. I would like to write is if the patterncontains "00" or finish in "00".